# PHPExcel $objWriter->save() fails without an Exception

Tags: php, phpexcel

I know that there are many similar questions and I read them all. But my problem is, that I don't even get any error message.

I got this code:

```
    PrintOut::msg("startsaving");
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->reader, $this->inputFileType);
    try {
        $objWriter->save("C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\\".$this->filename);
    } catch (PHPExcel_Writer_Exception $e) {
        PrintOut::msg($e->getMessage());
    }
    PrintOut::msg("TEST");
```

The thing is, that I don't get any exception thrown, BUT I also don't get my 'Test' printed. So my script is hanging somewhere in the saving process but nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea, what could be the problem?

Funny thing: It worked on another computer with the same code before.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs?

Comment: @MarkBaker: Yes. And there is nothing.

Comment: Then I haven't  a clue.... the folder exists? (it is better to escape slashes `\\` when they appear in strings) and also to use unix style folder names (even on Windows)

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried almost everything with the path. But the mistake can't lie there. I even use the same thing when opening the excel. And this works.

Comment: Then I'm completely without a clue.... with no exceptions thrown, or anything in the log, there's nothing that gives any indication what the problem might be

Comment: @MarkBaker Ohh I found the mistake. There must have been an error when copying my workspace somehow. Because I donwloaded PHPExcel again and used the new files. Now it works. But thank you anyway for thinking about my problem!